# AJAX - Codeigniter Object Object

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter

Al pasar la data a procesar a un controlador de Codeigniter y al hacer su impresión obtengo Object Object.

¿Alguien me podría decir por favor qué está mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Al imprimir es lo que veo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue simple.

En la vista:

```
// Almaceno en el storage la data que recibo inicialmente
window.localStorage.setItem('emails_data', data);

// Confirmando la acción
$("#btnConfirm").click(function() {
            var base_url = '<?= base_url() ?>';
            var data = window.localStorage.getItem('emails_data');
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: base_url + "/index.php/email/prepareDataSendEmail",
                data: {'data':data},
                success: function(data) {
                    window.localStorage.removeItem('emails_data');
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    //Cuando la interacción retorne un error, se ejecutará esto.
                },
            });
        });
```

Al imprimir desde el controlador esto es lo que obtengo en consola:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date_init_send] => 2020-04-02 20:56:32
            [email_from] => clientes@example.com.co
            [email_to] => cristian.higuita@example.com
         )
)
```

Comment: Oh claro gracias :) ya lo corrijo, perdón es que soy nuevo en esto

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente la variable "emails_data" es un objeto o un array, y en el parámetro "data" del ajax, espera le pases un valor unico o un array como este:

```
data: {
    clave: "valor"
}
```

Pero probablemente estes enviando algo como esto:

```
data: {
    emails_data: { foo: "bar", bar: "foo"}
}
```

Lo cual no funcionará porque es un arreglo u objeto dentro de otro arreglo.

Comment: Hola Daniel, efectivamente es un arreglo, pero es que así me lo retornan desde el modelo, ¿hay alguna manera de pasarlo así al controlador? Es que no quisiera hacer otra petición a la BD desde el controlador para obtener la misma información

Comment: Podrias enviar directo el arreglo, colocandolo "data = data;  " en lugar de hacer otra asociación clave - valor. Le pasas la que ya tienes.

Comment: Buen día estimado he realizado exactamente lo que usted me dice, pero aún sigue presentando el mismo problema :/

Comment: En ese caso tendras que procesar previamente el valor que obtienes del localStorage antes de enviarlo al ajax, eso es tomar el arreglo recorrerlo e ir construyendo el array a enviarle al ajax. Para darte ayuda mas precisa, podrias ampliar tu consulta agregando el contenido de esa variable del localstorage (puedes alterar algunos valores si es data sensible), pero lo importante es ver la estructura que devuelve. Eso lo puedes obtener en la consola del explorador con un `console.log(window.localStorage("emails_data"));`

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo Daniel, ya pude resolverlo adjunto la solución por si alguno tiene esta especie de capa 8 jajaj